# Is it possible to get rid of the bullets in the miniframes outer theme

Tags: beamer, navigation, mini-frames

I actually like the bullets shown when using `\useoutertheme{miniframes}`, but for the long talk I have to give there are just ridiculously many.

[image: too many bullets]

Is it possible to keep the same theme and just removing the bullets, and then displaying slide numbers instead?

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[compress, final]{beamer}
    \usetheme[height=0mm]{Rochester}
    \usecolortheme{dolphin}
    \useinnertheme{rectangles}
    \useoutertheme[footline=empty, subsection=true]{miniframes}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test frame}
    \begin{block}<+->{Block}
        Beamer is cool
    \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note: Cross post with LaTeX Community because of urgent question. http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=12983&p=49388#p49388

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can modify the headline. For example:

```
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=3.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{section in head/foot}
    \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]{section in head/foot}%
    \insertsectionhead
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{middle separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
    leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{subsection in head/foot}
    \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\insertsubsectionhead
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
```

This is very similar to `miniframes` headline but it uses `\insertsectionhead` instead of `\insertnavigation` which includes those bullets.

Comment: Awesome, that is almost perfect. Thanks a lot at this point already. But it is it also possible to show all sections in the top bar, with the current one being highlighted?

Comment: Okay, I figured out how: `\insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\textwidth}{}{}`, maybe you can include this in your answer, although it is not aligned to the left and right to match the sub-section properly. Any idea?

Comment: I get the rigth text, but it occupies the same height that the bullet version, with a white space in top? any idea why?

Comment: It is not working for me

Comment: @emcor It is working as others confirmed above, you may do something different or have conflicting code in your preamble. Perhaps you post a new question with your details and your code.