# Removing bullets in headline with own template doesn't work

Tags: beamer, header-footer, mini-frames

I'm using Ilmenau in a beamer presentation (first image)

[image: outer theme miniframes /Ilmenau]

I want to hide the bullets, so I use my own headline template (I get the idea from [Is it possible to get rid of the bullets in the miniframes outer theme](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17288/is-it-possible-to-get-rid-of-the-bullets-in-useouterhememiniframes) ). I remove the bullets but I get a white box on top of the slide instead (second image). I want to remove the bullets and the rest of the header elements move to the top.

I'm using this code:

```
\usetheme{Ilmenau}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}{section in head/foot}
  \vskip2pt\insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\textwidth}{}{}\vskip2pt
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
```

[image: own header]

**UPDATE:** Complete snippet: The empty template output white space on top, but if you uncomment the headline template body, is more strange even.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\title{Active Galactic Nuclei}
\author{John Doe}
\usetheme{Ilmenau}
\usecolortheme[rgb={0,0.4,0}]{structure}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamercovered{transparent=20}
\newcommand*\oldmacro{}%
\let\oldmacro\insertshorttitle%
\renewcommand*\insertshorttitle{%
  \oldmacro\hfill%
  \insertframenumber}

\begin{document}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}[default]
 {%
%%   \begin{beamercolorbox}{section in head/foot}
%%   \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\textwidth}{}{}
%%   \end{beamercolorbox}%
}

\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Active Galactic Nuclei}

\frame{
\frametitle{Active Galactic Nuclei}
In some galaxies, the nucleus produces more radiation than the entire rest of the galaxy. Gas spirals towards a supermassive black hole (SMBH) assuming a disk shaped structure, generating massive amounts of radiation before falling onto the black hole. 
}

\section{Other}
\subsection{Other}

\frame{
\frametitle{Active Galactic Nuclei}
In some galaxies, the nucleus produces more radiation than the entire rest of the galaxy. Gas spirals towards a supermassive black hole (SMBH) assuming a disk shaped structure, generating massive amounts of radiation before falling onto the black hole. 
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: added the theme line

Comment: I added a complete example of the problem

Comment: how you did please to have the bullet in multiple line

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move the redefinition for `headline` to the preamble:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\title{Active Galactic Nuclei}
\author{John Doe}
\usetheme{Ilmenau}
\usecolortheme[rgb={0,0.4,0}]{structure}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamercovered{transparent=20}
\newcommand*\oldmacro{}%
\let\oldmacro\insertshorttitle%
\renewcommand*\insertshorttitle{%
  \oldmacro\hfill%
  \insertframenumber}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}
 {%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}{section in head/foot}
  \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\textwidth}{}{}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}

\begin{document}


\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Active Galactic Nuclei}

\frame{
\frametitle{Active Galactic Nuclei}
In some galaxies, the nucleus produces more radiation than the entire rest of the galaxy. Gas spirals towards a supermassive black hole (SMBH) assuming a disk shaped structure, generating massive amounts of radiation before falling onto the black hole. 
}

\section{Other}
\subsection{Other}

\frame{
\frametitle{Active Galactic Nuclei}
In some galaxies, the nucleus produces more radiation than the entire rest of the galaxy. Gas spirals towards a supermassive black hole (SMBH) assuming a disk shaped structure, generating massive amounts of radiation before falling onto the black hole. 
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: argg, it seem too obvious now!!