# How to get rid of points marking slide when using LaTeX Beamer theme Boadilla and get all subsections?

Tags: beamer, templates, themes

I have setting of Beamer presentation like this:

```
\documentclass[compress, xelatex]{beamer}
\usetheme[secheader]{Boadilla}
\usecolortheme{whale}
\useoutertheme[subsection=true]{miniframes}
\useinnertheme{circles}
\usefonttheme{structurebold}
\begin{document}
\section{A}
\begin{frame}{A}
A
\end{frame}
\subsection{B}
\begin{frame}{B}
B
\end{frame}
\subsection{C}
\begin{frame}{C}
C
\end{frame}
\section{D}
\begin{frame}{D}
D
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Head of the theme]

I like it, I just would like to get rid of those small bullets below section names and I would like to have all subsections in second line of the menu, with recent subsection highlighted. I don't wish to modify any other part of the theme (bottom line, colours, ...).

It is similar to [Is it possible to get rid of the bullets in the miniframes outer theme](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17288/is-it-possible-to-get-rid-of-the-bullets-in-the-miniframes-outer-theme) but solution there doesn't exactly what I wish. :-(

I finally got some working solution:

```
\documentclass[compress, xelatex]{beamer}
\usetheme[secheader]{Boadilla}
\usecolortheme{whale}
\useinnertheme{circles}

\setbeamertemplate{headline} {
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2ex]{section in head/foot}
\insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{\hskip0pt plus1fill}{\hskip0pt plus1fill}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2ex]{subsection in head/foot}
\insertsubsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{}{\hfill\hfill}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\section{A}
\begin{frame}{A}
A
\end{frame}
\subsection{B}
\begin{frame}{B}
B
\end{frame}
\subsection{C}
\begin{frame}{C}
C
\end{frame}
\section{D}
\begin{frame}{D}
D
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

So Hugo's link, Beamer's manual and link I was originally citing finally worked. So if anyone else would have same problem... Thank You.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56946/beamer-how-to-customise-the-header-of-a-frankfurt-slide
Maybe this can help

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Thank You for hints. I completed the code to show all my settings.  Hugo's link is interesting, but I'm unable to complete the code to get desired output. When I use first code from first answer as it is, compilation fails...

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, some of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Comment: And what exactly is wrong with the linked answer?

Comment: Well, the linked code didn't compiled correctly with other my settings. Actually, I solved it (see the second code in the question).

Comment: Great for finding an answer yourself! Would you like to post your code as an answer so that other people will find it easier?

Comment: Done, samcarter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution:

```
\documentclass[compress, xelatex]{beamer}
\usetheme[secheader]{Boadilla}
\usecolortheme{whale}
\useinnertheme{circles}

\setbeamertemplate{headline} {
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2ex]{section in head/foot}
\insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{\hskip0pt plus1fill}{\hskip0pt plus1fill}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2ex]{subsection in head/foot}
\insertsubsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{}{\hfill\hfill}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\section{A}
\begin{frame}{A}
A
\end{frame}
\subsection{B}
\begin{frame}{B}
B
\end{frame}
\subsection{C}
\begin{frame}{C}
C
\end{frame}
\section{D}
\begin{frame}{D}
D
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```