# Omitting the subsectioning bullets in the headline of the frame in Beamer

Tags: beamer, sectioning, header-footer

How is it possible to remove the bullets and make the size of the headline  (sectioning names) in a suitable height?

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=8mm,text margin right=8mm} 
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{fig1}}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\usepackage{textpos}
\newenvironment<>{examplefirst}[1]{%
\centering
  \setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white,bg=green!40!black}%
  \begin{block}#2{#1}}{\end{block}}
\mode<presentation> {

% Block defenition

\newenvironment<>{varblock}[2][.9\textwidth]{%
  \setlength{\textwidth}{#1}
  \begin{actionenv}#3%
    \def\insertblocktitle{#2}%
    \par%
    \usebeamertemplate{block begin}}
  {\par%
    \usebeamertemplate{block end}%
  \end{actionenv}}


\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
\begin{textblock*}{100mm}(.95\textwidth,-1cm)
\includegraphics[height=1cm,width=4cm]{fig1}
\end{textblock*}}




\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=3.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{section in head/foot}
     \insertsectionhead
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}

\usetheme{Frankfurt}

}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\title[Short title]{Full Title of the Talk} % The short title appears at the bottom of every slide, the full title is only on the title page

\author{Sthephen} % Your name
\institute[UC] % Your institution as it will appear on the bottom of every slide, may be shorthand to save space
{
UC \\ % Your institution for the title page
\medskip
\textit{a} % Your email address
}
\date{\today} % Date, can be changed to a custom date

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage % Print the title page as the first slide
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Overview} % Table of contents slide, comment this block out to remove it
\tableofcontents % Throughout your presentation, if you choose to use \section{} and \subsection{} commands, these will automatically be printed on this slide as an overview of your presentation
\end{frame}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PRESENTATION SLIDES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=3.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{section in head/foot}
     \insertsectionhead
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}
%------------------------------------------------
\section{First Section} % Sections can be created in order to organize your presentation into discrete blocks, all sections and subsections are automatically printed in the table of contents as an overview of the talk
%------------------------------------------------



\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Paragraphs of Text}
a
\end{frame}


%------------------------------------------------

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Multiple Columns}
\begin{columns}[c] % The "c" option specifies centered vertical alignment while the "t" option is used for top vertical alignment

\column{.45\textwidth} % Left column and width
\textbf{Heading}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Statement
\item Explanation
\item Example
\end{enumerate}

\column{.5\textwidth} % Right column and width
a
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

%------------------------------------------------
\section{Second Section}
%------------------------------------------------


\end{document}
```

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17288/is-it-possible-to-get-rid-of-the-bullets-in-the-miniframes-outer-theme

Comment: Thanks. But it is not the thing that I want. I want to have the same format just without bullets.

Comment: The link @samcarter suggested addresses the exact same issue. Don't look at the image. Read the question and answer.

Comment: Thanks. I edited the code in that way but it does not show all the sections on the headline!

Comment: Your original doesn't show all the sections in the headline either. This is just as well, I would think, as it would quickly exceed the available space unless you give extremely short presentations and/or pick very, very concise section titles.

Comment: Yes, this is my problem that the whole sections is not shown.

Comment: @Stephen: Then *please* edit your question to make it clear!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Straight from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17301/36296 and its comments:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=3.5ex,dp=2.125ex]{section in head/foot}
    \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{section in head/foot}%
    \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\textwidth}{}{}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Overview}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\section{First Section}
\subsection{Subsection Example}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Paragraphs of Text}
a
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Multiple Columns}
  \begin{columns}[c]
    \column{.45\textwidth}
    \textbf{Heading}
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item Statement
      \item Explanation
      \item Example
    \end{enumerate}

    \column{.5\textwidth}
    a
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\section{Second Section}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So what was all that about the width? @Stephen did you mean height as samcarter suggested?

Comment: The solution by @samcarter is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

You want to do basically the same thing as the linked question. At least, as far as your question goes, that's what it seems. I don't understand the width  bit, though, so I'm only addressing the elimination of the dots.

This is just [Stefan Kottwitz's code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17301/), adapted a little.

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=8mm,text margin right=8mm}
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{fig1}}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textpos}
\newenvironment<>{examplefirst}[1]{%
  \centering
  \setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white,bg=green!40!black}%
  \begin{block}#2{#1}}{\end{block}}
\newenvironment<>{varblock}[2][.9\textwidth]{%
  \setlength{\textwidth}{#1}
  \begin{actionenv}#3%
    \def\insertblocktitle{#2}%
    \par%
    \usebeamertemplate{block begin}}
  {\par%
    \usebeamertemplate{block end}%
  \end{actionenv}}

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
  \begin{textblock*}{100mm}(.95\textwidth,-1cm)
    \includegraphics[height=1cm,width=4cm]{fig1}
  \end{textblock*}}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\title[Short title]{Full Title of the Talk}
\author{Sthephen}
\institute[UC]
{
  UC \\
  \medskip
  \textit{a}
}
\date{\today}
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{% ateb Stefan Kottwitz: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17301/
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=3.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{section in head/foot}
    \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{section in head/foot}%
    \insertsectionhead
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{middle separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
    leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{section in head/foot}
    \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{section in head/foot}%
    \insertsubsectionhead
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Overview}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\section{First Section}
\subsection{Subsection Example}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Paragraphs of Text}
a
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Multiple Columns}
  \begin{columns}[c]
    \column{.45\textwidth}
    \textbf{Heading}
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item Statement
      \item Explanation
      \item Example
    \end{enumerate}

    \column{.5\textwidth}
    a
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\section{Second Section}
\end{document}
```

That is, I presume the target is something like this:

[image: target, presumed]

I tried it with alternating blue/black but it looked weird. Besides, it is all black in the original, so I assume that is what is wanted.

Comment: Thanks @cfr. But, I mean that it simply shows "First Section" and "Second Section" in headline (whole sections without mentioning "Subsection Example" in a proper width like footline).

Comment: It clearly has `Subsection Example`. Of course it isn't in the footline: you said you wanted to change the headline. So that's what I changed.

Comment: You didn't get the point. I need the headline with only the same "width" as footline, with whole sections in headline.

Comment: @Stephen Are you talking about the height?