# Customization of sections and subsections in a metropolis Beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, sectioning, header-footer, beamer-metropolis, subsection

I have been working on a slide presentation with beamer. Thanks to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/686717/how-can-i-modify-the-following-headline-to-make-the-letters-bigger) I have the following code which generates slides that have a header with the section and the subsection as

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\graphicspath{{./Figures/}}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\setbeamercolor{progress bar}{fg=orange,bg=green}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{% 
  {\usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=3.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{section in head/foot}
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{section in head/foot}%
    \insertsectionhead
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{middle separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  {\usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
    leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{subsection in head/foot}
    \insertsubsectionhead
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\makeatother

\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=normal text.bg, bg=structure.fg}

\setbeamerfont{section in head/foot}{size=\small}
\setbeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}{size=\small}

\begin{document}


\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Subsection}

\begin{frame}{Introduction}

    \begin{center}
    I have text here
    \end{center}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Now, I was wondering if there exists a way to include subsubsections but in only a single slide e.g., add another line to the header for a single slide and then manually introduce the name of the sububsection, something like

[image: question]

While the others slides just have `Section` and `Subsection` at the beggining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an up-to-date beamer version (v3.70 or newer), you could temporarily add another box to the headline like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\graphicspath{{./Figures/}}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme
\setbeamercolor{progress bar}{fg=orange,bg=green}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{% 
  {\usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=3.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{section in head/foot}
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{section in head/foot}%
    \insertsectionhead
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{middle separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  {\usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
    leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{subsection in head/foot}
    \insertsubsectionhead
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\makeatother

\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=normal text.bg, bg=structure.fg}
\setbeamercolor{subsubsection in head/foot}{fg=normal text.bg, bg=structure.fg}

\setbeamerfont{section in head/foot}{size=\small}
\setbeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}{size=\small}
\setbeamerfont{subsubsection in head/foot}{size=\small}

\begin{document}


\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}

\begingroup
\addtobeamertemplate{headline}{}{
  {\usebeamerfont{subsubsection in head/foot}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
    leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{subsubsection in head/foot}
    \insertsubsubsectionhead
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
}
\begin{frame}{Introduction}

    \begin{center}
    I have text here
    \end{center}

\end{frame}
\endgroup

\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. However, I have copied it literally, but I am not getting the subsubsection in the first slide. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @slow_learner Is your beamer version up to date?

Comment: @slow_learner With "first slide" do you mean the frame with `I have text here`  or do your mean the section page for the introduction?

Comment: Thanks again. I have edited the question so you can see what I am getting. I think that my beamer is up to date, since it doesnt give me any issue anywhere else. I will try however to update the package

Comment: @slow_learner Check your .log file. You need beamer v3.70 for this to work.

Comment: `Document Class: beamer 2021/03/19 v3.62 A class for typesetting presentation` So I guess that I need an update

Comment: @slow_learner yes

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the explanation. It works now

Comment: @slow_learner Great to hear it is working!